# jquery to remove entry select dropdown if selection in another dropdown

Tags: jquery, html-select

Given this html:
[code](http://jsfiddle.net/dwvYY/6/)
I'd like a selection of b in Select d1 to result in option 2 in select r1 to not be avaialble (removed).  But if the page is refreshed or any other option is selected in d1, all options in r1 should be available.

Is this possible with Jquery?  http://jsfiddle.net/dwvYY/6/

One initial problem I'm having is I can't seem to refrence the select with the title property which my client tool (SharePoint is placing on Select tags).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could disable option by index or hide it.
Here is my solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/PabZk/

Selecting options by index would be a good idea in larger lists.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this code snippet gives you a clue how to implement it, you should consider to use a switch statement intsted.

If you choose b number 3 will be disabled in the other select list, have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dwvYY/7/

```
$("select[title$=d1]").change(function (){
    // Reset the options:
    $("select[title$=r1]").children("option").removeAttr("disabled","disabled")
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    if(selectedValue =="b"){

        // This will disable one option            
        $("select[title$=r1]").children("option[value='3']").attr("disabled","disabled")
    }
})
​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){

    $("select[title=d1]").change(function(){

       if($(this).val()=="b")
       {
           $("select[title=r1] option[value='2']").remove();
       }          
       else
       {
              $("select[title=r1] option[value='2']").remove();               
              $("select[title=r1] option[value='1']").after($("<option></option>").attr("value","2").text("2"));
       }               
    });        
})​
```

Working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/r34Kd/9/

Comment: works great on my sharePoint newform without having to set it to custom. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should answer both of your questions. First, in your jsFiddle, your code was being run in the head of the document instead of onLoad or onDOMready. Second, this code should do what you asked for in terms of removing "2" from the second list when "b" is selected from the first:

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bsP6W/)**.

jQuery:

```
$('select[title$=r1] option:eq(0)').text("Please Select").val("");
$('select[title$=d1] ').click(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'b') {
        $('select[title$=r1] option[value="2"]').remove();
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen for the `change` event in order for the values to change dynamically:

```
$('select[title="rl"]').change(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var options = $('' + $this + ' option');
  options.each(function() {
    // perform actions on each option value
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just show/hide the required option conditionally on `change` event of select element. Try this.

```
var $selectr1 = $('select[title=r1]');
$('select[title=d1]').change(function(){
    $selectr1.find("option").show();
    if(this.value == "b"){
        $selectr1.find("option[value='2']").hide();
    }
});
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/dwvYY/8/